# Summing Columns and replacing individual values if met specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas

d = {'col1': [25,20,30],
     'col2': [25,20,30],
     'col3': [25,20,30], 
     'col4': [25,39,11]
     }

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How would I loop from this data frame and add col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 and if not equal 100, take value in that index perform this col1/(col1+col2+col3+col4 and make that the new value for that spot. This way now when you sum col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 it will add up to 100 for that index.

So for example for index 0, when you add col1 +col2 + col3 + col4 it equals 100, therefore, go to the next index, however for index 1 it adds up to 99 so take 20/99 and make it the new value of that position, etc.

expected output:

```
d = {'col1': [25,20/99,30/101],
     'col2': [25,20/99,30/101],
     'col3': [25,20/99,30/101], 
     'col4': [25,39/99,11/101]
     }

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: please add the expected output too (similar to the input dataframe)

Comment: why do you not divide `25/99` in index 1?

Comment: because 25+25+25+25 = 100, it based on index not the values in the column

Answer (score 2):

here is a vectorized version:

```
c = df.sum(1).ne(100)
vals = np.where(c[:,None],df.div(df.sum(1),axis=0),df)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(vals,index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
# for overwriting the original df , use: df[:] = vals
print(new_df)
```

---

```
       col1      col2      col3       col4
0  25.00000  25.00000  25.00000  25.000000
1   0.20202   0.20202   0.20202   0.393939
2   0.29703   0.29703   0.29703   0.108911
```

Answer (score 0):

This achieves what you want by first generating each column as a list of its own:

```
col = [d[row][i] for row in d]
```

The process you describe is then applied:

```
if sum(col) != 100:
        newcol = [n/sum(col) for n in col]
```

and then the column can be re-inserted. Final product:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    col = [d[row][i] for row in d]
    if sum(col) != 100:
        newcol = [n/sum(col) for n in col]
    else:
        newcol = col.copy()
    for row in d:
        d[row][i] = newcol[int(row[-1:])-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this method to resolve my question

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    x = (df.loc[i,'col1']+df.loc[i,'col2']+df.loc[i,'col3']+df.loc[i,'col4'])
    for j in range(0,4):
        df.iloc[i,j] = (df.iloc[i,j])/(x)
```